# React throwing error on using hooks without class name prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

When I use hooks without class name prefix it's throwing error.
Please help me fix it

```
import React, {Fragment,useState} from 'react';

function App (props) {
  const [x,updateX] = useState(1) /* 
throwing error without the - 
React class name, like - 
React.useState(value)
 */
  
  return (
    //same here
    <Fragment> 
      <h2>This is app.js {x}</h2>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Why does the question have irrelevant tags?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provide here the expected result is `This is app.js 1`

Which I have just reproduced like this,

```
import React,{ Fragment, useState } from "react";

function App(props) {
  const [x,updateX] = useState(1)
  return (
    <Fragment> 
    <h2>This is app.js {x}</h2>
  </Fragment>
);
}

export default App;
```

if you still facing an error probably need more context to solve it!!
The output I got[image]